# Solr schema.xml and lots of parameters

Tags: parameters, solr, indexing

I'm going to index our products database in solr but I have one doubt. Our products are described by over 1000 parameters, approximately 20 for each. We have 100 000 products. Parameters are different, some of them are strings, some of them are exact numbers, some of them are numbers but needs to support ranges. So, my question is: should I prepare separate field for each parameter in schema.xml? We want to use these parameters as filters to narrow search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining all the fields in the schema you can define dynamic fields for each type and use that types in the client side.

For example : For integer type define the following dynamic field.

```
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Then create your integer fields as `fieldName_i`.

For more information check [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields).

Comment: I'm aware of such solution, thanks anyway, but there is one more problem. I'm affraid that some of parameters will have to be indexed twice. First I want to index only their ids, because i don't dont need  their exact values, second, for ranges, i'll need to index their values so solr can calculate them. Is it good approach?

Comment: Instead of updating, indexing all fields in the beginning seems more reasonable for me.If you do not need their values then you can set the stored parameter to false in the field definition.

Comment: Looks reasonable, but what if i need a list of parameters and their values to show user what by which parameters he can filter out the results? You know, something like in amazon's left column.

Comment: You should desing schema.xml file properly.If you think that you will need values then you should set stored to true, otherwise false.Or you can make two dynamic dynamic fields such as: <dynamicField name="*_i_stored"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>, <dynamicField name="*_i_not_stored"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="false"/>